# Calculator in C - switch statement not working

Tags: scanf, calculator

I am trying to run this simple calculator code, and i don't know what's the problem with running this code.

After i enter the two operands (Num1 & Num2), the program automatically jumps to the switch default message,
i have trying to check same codes over the internet and they look exactly the same...

Can someone please point what am i doing wrong ?
(Running on visual studio 2017)
Thanks !

```
  int main() {
double Num1, Num2;
char operator;

printf("Enter first number:\n");
scanf("%lf", &Num1);

printf("Enter second number:\n");
scanf("%lf", &Num2);

printf("Enter operator: + or - ");
scanf("%c", &operator);

switch(operator)
{

case '+':
    printf("%.1lf + %.1lf = %.1lf", Num1, Num2, Num1 + Num2);
    break;

case '-':
    printf("%.1lf - %.1lf = %.1lf", Num1, Num2, Num1 - Num2);
    break;

default:
    printf("Operator is not correct");


}

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `scanf` leaves the newline in the buffer. This is no problem for your `float` reads, but the `char` read will fail because the newline is taken as a char and that doesn't match in your switch. You can fix it by changing your read to this:

```
scanf(" %c", &operator);
```

Note the space in `" %c"`. With this you're telling it to discard the leading whitespace (which in this case is the newline).

The [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) offers following explanation:

> whitespace characters: any single whitespace character in the format
>   string consumes all available consecutive whitespace characters from
>   the input (determined as if by calling isspace in a loop). Note that
>   there is no difference between "\n", " ", "\t\t", or other whitespace
>   in the format string

.